# How do I change column value in mysql DB after PayPal payment verification?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I looked and couldn't find an adequate answer for this so I'm turning the masses for help.

I have a php form that when submitted enters the field data into a mysql DB table and then goes on to PayPal for payment.  One of the table columns have a value of either "Paid" or "Unpaid".  The default is "Unpaid".

I have everything working correctly with the payment.php file from PayPal and utilizing the IPN, in that when a payment is made all the verification protocols work and I end up with transaction information in another DB table called "payments" the way I'm supposed to.

In a very long-winded way, what I'm trying to get at is this:

When all the IPN stuff works and the payment is verified, I want the value of the Paid/Unpaid column for that entry to change from "Unpaid" to "Paid".

I'm having a tough time figuring it out.  Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
mysql_query("UPDATE yourtable_name SET status = 'Paid' WHERE [payment_unique_id] = <acutal_payment_id>");
```

[payment_unique_id] is field which you use to uniquely identify the payment.

You could pass the payment_unique_id to paypal using custom field and get it back via the IPN response.

Answer (score 0):

save the inserted row id in session, in the return page when everything is verified update that row value to paid